# XOR暗号を使ってファイルの暗号化と復号化をしたいのですが、テキストファイル以外でうまくいきません

Tags: c

コード：

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

#define key 1234
#define SIZE 16

int main()
{

    int i;
    char str[SIZE];
    fpos_t ft;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.dat", "rb");
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test2.dat","wb");

    int j = 0;
    while(1){
        memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
        fseek(fp, j, SEEK_SET);
        fread(str, SIZE-1, 1, fp);

        for(i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
            fprintf(file, "%c", (char)(str[i] ^ key));
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        if(str[i+1]=='\0'){puts("a"); break;}
        //if(feof(fp)){printf("aaa"); break;}
        j += 15;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

小さめのテキストファイルでしか試してませんが、テキストファイルの場合はこのコードで暗号化復号化できます。
画像ファイルや実行ファイルで試すとうまくいきません。
このまま1.1MBくらいの画像ファイルで動かしてみると120バイトのファイルが出力されて、コメントアウトしてるif文に切り替えると1MBのファイルが出力されました。
どうすればいいと思いますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最初の回答にあるとおり、まず `strlen` がいけません。`fread`で読み込んだ長さを変数`n`で受け取り、読み込めなかった時はループを抜けるようにします。`n`の回数だけ`XOR`演算を行います。バイナリファイルに書き込むのに`fprintf`を使うのは、致命的に深刻な問題というほどではありませんが、あまり良くないやり方です。1文字出力するための関数`putc`がありますのでこれを使います。バイナリがコンソールに表示されると画面が乱れますので、`printf`や`puts`は消します。

特殊なコンピューターでなければ、`char`は8ビットです（この件に言及し始めると、`char`が8ビットであるとは限らないというつっこみが、たくさん飛んできます）ので、一般的なWindowsかMacかLinuxであると想定し、`char`の範囲は`-128`～`+127`の範囲であるものとします。ですので、`XOR`するための`key`の値が`1234`というのは適切ではありません。もし、`char`に`1234`を格納できるだけのサイズを持ったコンピューターなら間違いではないのですが、恐らくそうではないと思うので、`key`の値は`char`の範囲に合わせて、小さめの値にしました。

`fseek`は必要ないので、変数`j`も消します。

```
#define key 123
#define SIZE 16

int main()
{

    int i;
    char str[SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("neko1.jpg", "rb");
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("neko2.jpg","wb");

    while (1) {
        int n = fread(str, 1, SIZE, fp);
        if (n < 1) break;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            putc(str[i] ^ key, file);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

とりあえずこれで動きますが、16バイト単位で処理するというのは、最近のコンピューターには控えめすぎるサイズです。1024や4096や65536などが好んで使われると思います。出力する際も、1バイトずつ`putc`でやるのもケチ臭いです。C言語の学習用サンプルプログラムか何かだと思いますが、実際に使えるプログラムにする場合、バッファのサイズ分まとめて暗号化の演算を行い、`putc`の代わりに`fwrite`で複数バイトまとめて書き込む、などの工夫ができますので、今後の課題として、挑戦してみるといいでしょう。

Comment: この方法とfwriteを使う方法で試して見ましたが両方うまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

`strlen(str)` がバイナリの場合期待するように働きません。
`\0`の場所に依存しないように
`fread`の返値を保存（`fread(str, 1, SIZE, fp);` にしてバイト数を返すようにしておきます）して、読み込んだバイト数で処理するようにします。

ちなみに`fseek`は必要無いです。

Comment: 無事動くようになりました。ありがとうございます。